# How to do it better in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For example I have 5 ranks like beginner, smarty, genius, etc. for users.

Each rank has its own score system. Do I think in right way to realize it like?

```
if ($score > 10) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->ranks = 'beginner';
    $user->save();
}
if ($score > 20) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->ranks = 'smarty';
    $user->save();
}
```

and 3 more if clause in this way

Comment: This may be a better question for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `$user = User::find($id);` and `$user->save();` occur for each case. How could you rearrange your code so that those two statements aren't repeated in each of the if statements? In your current code think about what happens when score is 25. Do both if statements evaluate to true, and is the user saved twice?

Comment: Is store stored with the user? If so, consider an accessor to return the rank rather than saving it to the database as unnecessarily duplicated info.

Answer (score 1):

1 solution (one request in db)

```
$data = []; 

if ($score > 10) {
    $data['ranks'] = 'beginner';
} elseif ($score > 20) {
    $data['ranks'] = 'smarty';
} elseif ('condition') {
    $data['ranks'] = 'new value';
} else {
    $data['ranks'] = 'default value';
}

User::where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

2 solution (two request in db, one for find user, second to update user)

```
$ranks = '';
if ($score > 10) {
    $ranks = 'beginner'
} elseif ($score > 20) {
    $ranks = 'smarty'
} elseif('condition') {
    $ranks = 'new value'
} else {
    $ranks = 'default value'
}

$user = User::find($id);
$user->ranks = $ranks;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::find($id);

if ($score > 40) {
    $user->ranks = 'genius';
} elseif ($score > 30){
    $user->ranks = 'smarty';
}   
...

$user->save();
```